# "showframe", how to make colored lines of page layout?

Tags: color, rules

In my answers here, on TeX.SS many times I like to show tables with width of `\textwidth` together with page layout. Since both lines are black, it is not  simple distinguish table vertical border lines and table top line from page layout. If the page layout lines be in for example blue, this would become more easier.

An example:

[image]

Above image is done by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \scriptsize
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\,}m{2cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{18}{c}@{\,}}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{17}{c}{APE Thresholds (\%)} &   
                            \\  \cmidrule(lr){2-18}
\centering  Model   
        & 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.25 & 0.5 &  1 &  2 & 5 
        & 7.5  & 10   & 15  & 30   & 40  & 50 & 75 & 100 
        & None & Best       \\  \midrule
Closed
        & 25   & 50   & 35  & 40   & 45  &    &    &  
        &      &      &     &      &     &    &    & 
        &      &            \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redeclare `\ShowFrameColor`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
    \scriptsize
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\,}m{2cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{18}{c}@{\,}}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{17}{c}{APE Thresholds (\%)} &
                            \\  \cmidrule(lr){2-18}
\centering  Model
        & 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.25 & 0.5 &  1 &  2 & 5
        & 7.5  & 10   & 15  & 30   & 40  & 50 & 75 & 100
        & None & Best       \\  \midrule
Closed
        & 25   & 50   & 35  & 40   & 45  &    &    &
        &      &      &     &      &     &    &    &
        &      &            \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

It is also possible to change the thickness of the lines with `\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{5pt}`

[image]

---

References

http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic/showframe.sty

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder, does exist similar solution for `showframe` option in `geometry` package?

Comment: I do not know of any, and looking at the relevant code in `geometry` makes me believe that it won't be easy to implement. Do you assume that `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` creates more accurate frames than `\usepackage{showframe}`?

Comment: No, I'm just curious. In case, that I use `geometry` packages, the option `showframe` become handy. But instead this option have one more package in preamble, is not so big deal. Because the name of option and package are the same, I hope, that they have some common parts of code.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164521 for the `showframe` option of `geometry`.

Comment: The same exact code gives me an error `! LaTeX Error: Command \ShowFrameColor undefined.`, showframe results installed.